# How to project a portion of a sphere to a plane preserving distance?

Tags: stereographic-projections

Stereographic projection preserves angles but not distances. I've been lead to believe that it isn't possible to go from a sphere to a plane preserving distances between points, but is it possible to do so with a segment of a sphere?

For context, I'm planning on using locations in the United States as inputs, and so I only would need to project the area of a sphere corresponding to the continental United States and Alaska (I'd likely just eyeball the numbers for Hawaii given it's distance from the rest of the states). Is there a way to preserve distance in this transformation of a subset of the sphere?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do it even for a segment of a sphere. The reason is essentially the same: a segment of the sphere is intrinsically curved, just as the whole sphere is.  If the segment is small relative to the whole sphere, the distortion will be relatively small; the approximation gets worse as the segment grows.  This is why local maps give approximately correct distances. For a region as large as the continental United States, the distortion will be substantial no matter what you do.

For exact distances, the best you can do is the various *equidistant projections*.  The [azimuthal equidistant projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection)  preserves the distances along any diameter of the map.  In particular, this means that the distance from the center point $P$ to any other point is correct.

In the [equidistant conic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistant_conic_projection), distances are correct along two particular parallels.